# abi.encodeWithSignature and abi.encode have inconsistent results with dynamic arrays

Tags: solidity, abi, encoding, abi.encodewithsignature

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

function isMemberOfArrayEncodedTest(address member, address [] memory memberArray) public returns (string memory){
        bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("isMemberOfArray(address,address[])"));
        bytes memory param1 = abi.encode(member);
        bytes memory param2 = abi.encode(memberArray);
        
        bytes memory data = abi.encodePacked(sig,param1,param2);
        bytes memory proof = abi.encodeWithSelector(sig,member,memberArray);
```

```
data =  0x59f4d3660000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4 

proof = 0x59f4d3660000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4
```

per the solidity documentation, `abi.encodeWithSelector` should run `abi.encode` on each of it's arguments. The output for `data` and `proof` should be identical, but they diverge by one character in the beginning of where the dynamic array gets encoded.

`encode`:

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020`

`encodeWithSelector`:

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040`

Comment: so i figured it out the abi expects you to encode the args as a tuple so
instead of:
abi.encodePacked(sig, abi.encode(member), abi.encode(memberArray))
i had to do:
abi.encodePacked(sig, abi.encode(member, memberArray)

Comment: You should never use packed encoding for any type of argument or calldata encoding. Packed encoding is discouraged. It's useful for hashing simple strings by stripping length data, but not much else.